# Range Error in one program but works fine in another program

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm pretty new to this so sorry if the answer is obvious. Basically i have this program named testing stuffs that's been made by someone else, where you can draw multiple children out of a movie clip and it works fine.
However the other one, in which i've transplanted and adapted the code gives me an error

RangeError: Error #1125: The index -1 is out of range 13.
    at jocAmare2_fla::MainTimeline/endDragIt()

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ciy0l2s7hys5lte/test%20stuffs%20for%20the%20things.fla

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9m5s98hq3d3jkrs/joc%20Amare%202.fla

i've added the code in pastebins because i didn't want to have a wall of text here

working: http://pastebin.com/bnV5dnUt

not working: http://pastebin.com/8sUeyntW

Comment: I'm not going to dig through .fla files, because I don't have the appropriate programs to open those (I don't use CS6 or whatever you're using). Can you copy the relevant scripts and edit your question to include them?

Comment: i've edited it to include pastebins of the codes

Answer (score 0):

```
function endDragIt(evt:Event)
{
    var target:MovieClip = evt.target as MovieClip;

    target.stopDrag();

    var i:int = isOver();

    if (target.dropTarget != null && casete.indexOf(target.dropTarget.parent) != -1)
    {

        target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,dragIt);
        target.mouseEnabled = false;

        var caseta:MovieClip = casete[i];

        var clasaTarget = Object(target).constructor;


        if (clase[i] == clasaTarget)
        {
            trace("Bravo!");
            trace("Ai facut bine!");
            score+=3/5;
            target.x = caseta.x;
            target.y = caseta.y;
            trace("Scor ok="+score);
            if(score>1 && score<1.5){
                scorfinal=1;
                trace(scorfinal);
            }
            if(score>1.5 && score < 2.5){
                scorfinal=2;
                trace(scorfinal);
            }
            if(score>2.5){
                scorfinal=3;
                trace(scorfinal);
            }
        } 
        else
        {

            target.x=caseta.x;
            target.y=caseta.y;
            trace("gresit");
        }
    }else{
        target.x+=1000;
        target.y+=1000;
    }
}
```

That's the function that's causing the error...

And looking at it, I guess it goes wrong here:

```
var caseta:MovieClip = casete[i];
```

Because `i = -1`, and there's no `-1` in that array.

Now then...
Why does i get to -1?

It does so because `isOver()` returns -1.

It seems that's your problem. You stop dragging something...
and you're no longer over the object you selected. Huh.
How strange.

Looking at the other code, I don't see much difference.

My suggestion to you: Alter both applications to trace information in the isOver() function. Check if anything is different in the output. Particularily of interest are the calculations made with width and height.

```
function isOver():int{
    for(var i:int = 0; i<casete.length; i++){

        if(this.mouseX >= casete[i].x-casete[i].width/2 && this.mouseX <= casete[i].x+casete[i].width/2)
            if(this.mouseY >= casete[i].y-casete[i].height/2 && this.mouseY <= casete[i].y+casete[i].height/2)
                return i;
    }

    return -1;

}
```

I would change that function to

```
function isOver():int{
    trace("isOver called");
    trace("mouseX: "+this.mouseX+", mouseY:"+this.mouseY);
    for(var i:int = 0; i<casete.length; i++){
        trace("testing casete "+i);
        trace("x lower bound:"+(casete[i].x-casete[i].width/2)+", x upper bound:"+(casete[i].x+casete[i].width/2));
        trace("y lower bound:"+(casete[i].y-casete[i].height/2)+", y upper bound:"+(casete[i].y+casete[i].height/2));
        if(this.mouseX >= casete[i].x-casete[i].width/2 && this.mouseX <= casete[i].x+casete[i].width/2)
            if(this.mouseY >= casete[i].y-casete[i].height/2 && this.mouseY <= casete[i].y+casete[i].height/2)
                return i;
    }

    return -1;

}
```

What you should be seeing, ideally, is no difference between the two programs.

If that's the case, then you've stumbled onto another bug; the assumption that you're still over the object when the mouse is released is false. If there IS a difference between the two programs (when performing a similar action!), your implementation of the rest could be wrong.